# How to empty a list in Tcl?

Tags: tcl

How do you empty a list in Tcl efficiently?

I have tried using lreplace to empty a list, for example:

```
set lst "a b c d e"  
lreplace $lst 0 [[llength $lst] - 1]  # replace all content in the list with "".
```

Comment: If you don't need to variable anymore, `unset lst`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The empty string is an efficient value to use.

```
set lst {}
```

You can use `[list]` with no arguments instead of `{}`; that compiles to the same thing.

Comment: IMHO this is the idiomatic way to do it

Comment: I did a google search on "how to empty a list in tcl" but can't really find a solution to this simple question. I guess tcl is just that unpopular. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

How about: `set lst [list]`

References: [list](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Note that

```
% lreplace $lst 0 [[llength $lst] - 1]
invalid command name "5"
```

will not work (it tries to execute the command substitution `5 - 1`, which fails if it can't find any command named `5`).

This is a step closer:

```
% lreplace $lst 0 end
```

but still fails since it just produces the value of the items in the list with the items from `0` to `end` replaced with nothing. The contents of the variable `lst` aren't changed.

This is how you do it*

```
% set lst [lreplace $lst 0 end]
```

By assigning the result of the `lreplace` back to the variable `lst`, you make the replacement effective in the variable value.

*) this is not actually how you do it, because it's overkill. The value of `lreplace $lst 0 end` is equal to the empty string, so just assign that:

```
% set lst {}
```

Documentation:
[lreplace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lreplace.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

*Syntax of Tcl index expressions:*

- *integer* zero-based index number
- `end` the last element
- `end`*-N* the *n*th element before the last element
- `end`*+N* the *n*th element after the last element (in practice, *N* should be negative)
- *M-N* the *n*th element before element *m*
- *M+N* the *n*th element after element *m*

There can be no whitespace within the expression.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I do wanna apologize that I did not really run the "llreplace" command, I was just trying to get pass stackoverflow to submit the very simple question "how to empty a list in tcl efficiently".